# Multiple foreach?

Tags: php, forms, foreach

I have to use a foreach Operation because my amount of form items is not known, my form looks like this:

`<form> <Input type="hidden" Name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id, ?>"> <Input type="text" Name="text[]" > <Input type="text" Name="text2[]"></form>`

Submit does $_POST

And on the post-page it should do:

`(foreach)  (SQL) "Update table SET text=$text[], text2=$text[] WHERE id = $id[]"`

How can this be solved?

Comment: By using a loop?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is formatted as such, you could do something like:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $i => $id) {
    $query = 'UPDATE `table` SET `text` = "'. $_POST['text'][$i] .'", `text2`="'. $_POST['text2'][$i] .'" WHERE `id` = '. $id;
}
```

Even better; let html send a multidimensional array, but you'll have to add indices yourself. But because you already have an id, you can use that one as an index:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="item[<?php echo $id; ?>]['text']">
    <input type="text" name="item[<?php echo $id; ?>]['text2']">
</form>
```

Then you can just foreach the items:

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $id => $values) {
   $query = 'UPDATE `table` SET `text` = "'. $values['text'] .'", `text2` = "'. $values['text2'] .'" WHERE `id` = $id";
}
```

Be sure to add prevention to SQL injection though!!!

Comment: and i do :  WHERE `id` = "'.$values['id´].'"  is that correct?

Comment: No, actually your id is in the `$id` variable, but you could add an hidden input field (although it's useless); `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="x">`

Comment: I've added the where clause, and editted the first example (in which I made a mistake...)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $val) {
    echo "KEY: ".$key." VAL: ".$val."<br>";
}
```

That will simply print out all $_POST keys and there values.

From there, add them into your statement.

Comment: I may have misunderstood this question